# cloned SSD to NVME but system boots from SSD everytime

Tags: boot, grub2, ssd, nvme

I had a running Ubuntu 18.04 system with single 250 GB SSD , I cloned it to my new NVME of exact same space . Now in EFI I gave NVME higher boot priority then SSD , but still the system loads Ubuntu from SSD instead of NVME .

But if I disable SSD port then only system boots from Ubuntu from NVME.

How can I get my system to boot from NVME without disabling SSD ?

Comment: Since you cloned the HDD they have same partition guid so you cannot control which partition grub matches first.  You need to modify one of the guid.

Comment: yes I guess that's exactly I want to fix , how can I change guid , should I regenerate grup config ?